# How to extract the longitude and the latitude from a CLLocation variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have an array with 10 entries. Each entry has an object of type "CustomeObj". In each object I stored an NSString and a CLLocation var. (Something like: "John", "(23.33f, -32.44f)) as map reference.

Now, I'd like to access those numbers inside the CLLocation variable:

NSLog (@"%f", obj.cllVar->latitude); returns 0,0000 but the real lat var, in the debugger, has a real value. Is there a wat to either double concatenate: "obj.cllVar.lat" or is there another way of pulling the lat or long. out of that cllVar out using a different operator

Thanks much.

Comment: obj.cllVar->latitude   is a string or float type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just dig into `CLLocation` getting the CLLocationCoordinate2D which contains lat & lon:

```
CLLocation *location = ...
CLLocationDegrees latitude  = location.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [locations and maps programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1) can provide a lot of help working with device location. Techtopia also provides a [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_Location_Application) on usage of the CLLocationManager. Here's a snippet that references a CLLocation variable with `newLocation.coordinate.latitude` and longitude as `newLocation.coordinate.longitude` (please see sources for more information):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
                  fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
     NSString *currentLatitude = [[NSString alloc] 
                  initWithFormat:@"%g", 
                  newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
     latitude.text = currentLatitude;

     NSString *currentLongitude = [[NSString alloc] 
          initWithFormat:@"%g",
          newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
     longitude.text = currentLongitude;

     NSString *currentHorizontalAccuracy = 
              [[NSString alloc] 
             initWithFormat:@"%g",
             newLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
     horizontalAccuracy.text = currentHorizontalAccuracy;

     NSString *currentAltitude = [[NSString alloc] 
                  initWithFormat:@"%g",                                                          
                  newLocation.altitude];
     altitude.text = currentAltitude;

     NSString *currentVerticalAccuracy = 
              [[NSString alloc] 
              initWithFormat:@"%g",
              newLocation.verticalAccuracy];
     verticalAccuracy.text = currentVerticalAccuracy;

     if (startLocation == nil)
            self.startLocation = newLocation;

     CLLocationDistance distanceBetween = [newLocation
            distanceFromLocation:startLocation];

     NSString *tripString = [[NSString alloc] 
           initWithFormat:@"%f", 
           distanceBetween];
     distance.text = tripString;
}
```